# Regex match strings divided by 'and'

Tags: python, regex, regex-group

I need to parse a string to get desired number and position form a string, for example:

```
2 Better Developers and 3 Testers
5 Mechanics and chef
medic and 3 nurses
```

Currently I am using code like this which returns list of tuples, like `[('2', 'Better Developers'), ('3', 'Testers')]`:

```
def parse_workers_list_from_str(string_value: str) -> [(str, str)]:
    result: [(str, str)] = []
    if string_value:
        for part in string_value.split('and'):
            result.append(re.findall(r'(?: *)(\d+|)(?: |)([\w ]+)', part.strip())[0])
    return result
```

Can I do it without `.split()` using only regex?

Comment: What is the desired output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Together with `re.MULTILINE` you can do everything in one regex, that will also split everything correctly:

```
>>> s = """2 Better Developers and 3 Testers
5 Mechanics and chef
medic and 3 nurses"""
>>> re.findall(r"\s*(\d*)\s*(.+?)(?:\s+and\s+|$)", s, re.MULTILINE)
[('2', 'Better Developers'), ('3', 'Testers'), ('5', 'Mechanics'), ('', 'chef'), ('', 'medic'), ('3', 'nurses')]
```

With explanation and conversion of empty `''` to `1`:

```
import re

s = """2 Better Developers and 3 Testers
5 Mechanics and chef
medic and 3 nurses"""

results = re.findall(r"""
    # Capture the number if one exists
    (\d*)
    # Remove spacing between number and text
    \s*
    # Caputre the text
    (.+?)
    # Attempt to match the word 'and' or the end of the line
    (?:\s+and\s+|$\n?)
    """, s, re.MULTILINE|re.VERBOSE)

results = [(int(n or 1), t.title()) for n, t in results]
results == [(2, 'Better Developers'), (3, 'Testers'), (5, 'Mechanics'), (1, 'Chef'), (1, 'Medic'), (3, 'Nurses')]
```

Comment: It will match `123 foo` also where there is no `and`

Comment: @anubhava It's fine though, what's wrong with that? Same functionality as his regex.

Comment: @anubhava `and` is always given

Comment: @Bharel there can be no 'end' tho, like "3 Engineers"

Comment: @Recently_Created_User alright, so I take care of that as well, and for multiple "ands".

Comment: Please [check this demo](https://ideone.com/7NKq0w). It is producing result `[(3, 'Engineers')]` for input `3 Engineers` which doesn't contain any `and`

Comment: @Recently_Created_User I don't understand, you want it to always work or take only ones with `"and"`

Comment: @anubhava I have no clue what does the OP want at this point

Comment: @anubhava I've double checked, your solution works perfectly, thank you very much!

Comment: @Bharel Sorry mate, i mean 'and', not 'end', typo, but after checking demo i've found no problem in the code. Thank you guys very much!

Comment: @Recently_Created_User I'm glad I could help. If my solution has solved your problem, please be free to click the checkmark next to it and [accept it as the answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235). This lets other users know that your question was solved and awards us both a reputation bonus.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to handle multiple `and` splitters then you should consider using `PyPi regex` module that allows us to use **branch reset group** i.e. `(?!...)` that provides *Subpatterns* declared within each alternative of this construct will start over from the same index.

```
(?|(\d*) *(\b[a-z]+(?: [a-z]+)*?)(?= and )|(?<= and )(\d*) *(\b[a-z]+(?: [a-z]+)*))
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/hlI9BK/2)

```py
import regex
rx = regex.compile(r'(?|(\d*) *(\b[a-z]+(?: [a-z]+)*?)(?= and )|(?<= and )(\d*) *(\b[a-z]+(?: [a-z]+)*))', regex.I)

arr = ['2 Better Developers and 3 Testers', '5 Mechanics and chef', 'medic and 3 nurses', '5 foo', '5 Mechanics and 2 chefs and tester']
for s in arr: print (rx.findall(s), ':', s)
```

**Output:**

```
[('2', 'Better Developers'), ('3', 'Testers')] : 2 Better Developers and 3 Testers
[('5', 'Mechanics'), ('', 'chef')] : 5 Mechanics and chef
[('', 'medic'), ('3', 'nurses')] : medic and 3 nurses
[] : 5 foo
[('5', 'Mechanics'), ('2', 'chefs'), ('', 'tester')] : 5 Mechanics and 2 chefs and tester
```

---

**Earlier Answer** that was posted as per the original question with presence of single `and`.

You may use this regex:

```py
(\d*) *(\S+(?: \S+)*?) and (\d*) *(\S+(?: \S+)*)
```

Here we match `and` surrounded with a single space on either side. Before and after `and` we match using this sub-pattern:

```sh
(\d*) *(\S+(?: \S+)*?)
```

Which match optional 0+ digits to start with followed by 0 or more spaces followed by 1 or more non-whitespace strings separated by a space.

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/mkAYqM/1)

**Code:**

```py
import re
arr = ['2 Better Developers and 3 Testers', '5 Mechanics and chef', 'medic and 3 nurses', '5 foo']

rx = re.compile(r'(\d*) *(\S+(?: \S+)*?) and (\d*) *(\S+(?: \S+)*)')

for s in arr: print (rx.findall(s))
```

**Output:**

```py
[('2', 'Better Developers', '3', 'Testers')]
[('5', 'Mechanics', '', 'chef')]
[('', 'medic', '3', 'nurses')]
[]
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer!
However, what to do if there can be more than one 'and'?